date time comparison in oracle sql - sql developer
I'm trying to run a query and want to verify the date criteria I'm using. Is TO_DATE('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') the same as TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')? This would be the start date I'm trying to verify. I'm using oracle sql in sql developer.
Thanks

In Oracle, a DATE is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It ALWAYS has those components and it is NEVER stored in any particular human-readable format.
When you use TO_DATE and do not specify parts of the date then the defaults will be (as per the SQL Data-Types documentation):

The default date values are determined as follows:

The year is the current year, as returned by SYSDATE.
The month is the current month, as returned by SYSDATE.
The day is 01 (the first day of the month).
The hour, minute, and second are all 0.


If you use:
WITH dates (dt) AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('2016-01','YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT dt,
       DUMP(dt)
FROM   dates

Then the output is identical for all rows:



DT
DUMP(DT)




2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,1,1,1,1


2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,1,1,1,1


2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,1,1,1,1


2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,1,1,1,1



fiddle

Yes, they are the same. As mentioned in a slightly obscure place in the documentation:

In a DATE column:

The default time is 12:00:00 A.M. (midnight).
The default time applies to any value in the column that has no time portion, either because none was specified or because the value was truncated.
The default day is the first day of the current month.
The default date applies to any value in the column that has no date portion, because none was specified.


That wording is confusing because DATE values always have both date and time components, even if your client doesn't show them. But the examples in that section show what you are asking really, using to_date() without specifying all of the elements.
So, TO_DATE('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') both represent the same DATE value. You can see that by displaying the full value for both, or by using dump() to see that the internal representation is the same:
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

select TO_DATE('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
  dump(TO_DATE('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1016)
from dual;




TO_DATE('01/01/201600:00:00','MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS')
DUMP(TO_DATE('01/01/201600:00:00','MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS'),1016)




 2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=13 Len=8: e0,7,1,1,0,0,0,0



select TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),
  dump(TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'), 1016)
from dual;




TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')
DUMP(TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),1016)




 2016-01-01 00:00:00
Typ=13 Len=8: e0,7,1,1,0,0,0,0



fiddle
You can also use datetime literals like date '2016-01-01, or if you need to specify a time a timestamp literal cast as a date, like cast(timestamp '2016-01-01 00:00:00' as date). Those represent the same date value too - fiddle.
